# How to use props and print in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue JS 3 SFC and I have problem in displaying props to my component. It shows in the UI as an object: `{"title": "Home"}`

Here is my `Home` template:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Title :title={title} :styling={styling} />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Title from '../components/Title';

export default {
    name: 'Home',
    data() {
        return {
            title: 'Home',
            styling: 'text-center'
        }
    },
    components: { Title }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

and in my `Title` component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h5 class={styling}>{{ title }}</h5>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Title',
        props: { 
            title: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            styling: {
                type: String
            }
         },
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I want to know where did I go wrong and please advice me what is the proper way to do it. I am also new in Vue JS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you got the problem here. I think you don't need to wrap the value to brackets. You can still access the props but Vue.JS will read it as an object. I am not an expert but I also tried Vue.JS recently.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Title :title="title" :styling="styling" />
    </div>
</template>
```